# Why can't I see a DataGridView's properties?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2005, datagridview

I can't see DataGridView Properties in my C# program

in Visual studio 2005.

I can see the DataGridView on the Form - but can't see its Properties.

Why ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't see the designer properties window or the properties of that control don't show in the properties window or can't get the properties of the control show up in intellisense?..

Comment: Can't see the designer properties , i see the window - but empty

Comment: That's odd, I don't think I've run into that before, have you tried closing and re-opening VS.. also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sometimes you have select or reselect the control explicitly to get the properties window to pick up the selected control.

Comment: I am not sure on this but was there a datagridview with vs2005...just a thought..don't shoot me

Comment: fisthead is on to something, either Gold is confused about the actual classname or this is a VS2008 project mangled into VS2005

Answer (score 2):

This same thing happened to me because the full path of the project contained an '&'.  When I moved the project to a path that did not have an '&' everything worked.

Comment: 7 years old answer saved me in less than 7 minutes. I renamed the project folder replacing **&** with **and** then it worked as before.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem.  The DataGridView controls were the only ones not displaying properties in the properties window.  The DataGridView controls of mine in other projects were behaving properly and if I created a new project and dropped a DataGridView control in it, everything was fine.  To solve the issue, I deleted all of the files in the Properties and obj folder except for AssemblyInfo.cs, Resources.Designer.cs, Resources.resx, and SettingsDesigner.cs.  Not sure which one of the files that I deleted was responsible.

Answer (score 0):

With the form designer visible, go to the properties window.  Near the top will be a drop down list with all the controls.  Try selecting the control from the drop down list rather than from the canvas.  This also works well for controls that maybe hidden behind other controls.

Comment: I select the DataGridView from the drop down list - and i get error that visual-studio stop working and he close. what it can be ????

Comment: My guess is the designer file is corrupted or in is causing the problem.  Can you regenerate the form by hand?  Another option might be to try to force it to update the designer by going to designer mode editing something and bilding the project.  Other voodoo that might help would include restarting Visual Studio as Quintin mentioned.

Comment: thank's for the help, nothing help... it still the same problem

Comment: Can you try opening this project on another computer?  That will tell us if the problem is with the code or visual studio.

Comment: i try to open on another computer - same problem
i have many projects and its work excellent, only in this project i have problem

Comment: Another thing to try, first make a copy of your designer.cs file somewhere safe.  Then open up your designer and the designer.cs file, delete the contents of designer.cs and rebuild to trigger vs to rebuild the designer file.  You may want to take a look at the build log and post any errors or warnings here.  Try opening up the project properties and setting warnings to be treated as errors.